# Composition with ambiguous types

Tags: haskell

First time posting on this tag and I'm still taking tentative steps with the language, but I have some dynamic FP background, so I'm familiar with a few concepts already.

I've defined an `isZero` function.

```
isZero :: Int -> Bool
isZero x = x == 0
```

And I'm trying to compose it with the `mod` function to create an `isMultiple` function.

```
isMultiple = isZero . mod
```

However, this results in a type mismatch, because it's expecting the signature to be `a0 -> Int` and `mod` is `a0 -> a0 -> a0` (assuming this is because it supports multiple precisions).

I've noticed that if I just compose them explicitly (and provide a type signature), then there are no problems.

```
isMultiple :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isMultiple x n = isZero $ mod x n
```

Is there a way to use compose functions with ambiguous types using the `.` operator?

Comment: `\x -> isZero . mod x = \x -> (.) isZero (mod x) = (.) isZero . mod`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's have a look at the types in your first definition of `isMultiple`:

```
(.)            :: (b   -> c   ) -> (a ->   b          ) -> a -> c
isZero         ::  Int -> Bool
mod            ::                   Int -> Int -> Int
                    -- same as      Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

As you can see, both `b`'s aren't the same. That's why it doesn't work. However, one can get it to work, but that's not that easy to the eye anymore:

```
isMultiple = (isZero.) . mod
           = ((.) isZero) . mod
           = \x -> ((.) isZero) . mod $ x
           = \x -> ((.) isZero) (mod x) 
           = \x -> (.) isZero (mod x)
           = \x -> isZero . mod x
```

As you can see, `mod x` has type `Int -> Int`, and therefore is suitable for composition with `(.)` and `isZero`.

Comment: Ok, so the discrepancy is the LHS `b` expecting an `Int` but getting an `(Int -> Int)`? So the problem is composing a function that expects >= two arguments?

Comment: @DanPrince: Basically, yes (in THIS case; `map . mod` doesn't have this problem for example, but that has different semantics). But it's possible to get around this with another application of `(.)`. There's a [tool](http://pointfree.io/), but keep in mind that you want code to be readable by your drunk self in three months whenever possible.